# Python- How to delete all data between two constant delimiters-- parsing noisy HTML data

Tags: python, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing Wikipedia plain text data.  For whatever reason, appended to the end of each page, is the following text:

```
af:Vlermuis
ang:Hreaðemūs
ar:خفاش
an:Chiroptera
ast:Esperteyu
gn:Mbopi
ay:Chiñi
az:Yarasalar
bn:বাদুড়
zh-min-nan:Bi̍t-pô
be:Рукакрылыя
be-x-old:Рукакрылыя
bg:Прилепи
br:Askell-groc'hen
ca:Ratpenat
cv:Çара çерçи евĕрлисем
cs:Letouni
co:Topu pinnutu
cy:Ystlum
da:Flagermus
de:Fledertiere
nv:Jaaʼabaní Danilínígíí
et:Käsitiivalised
el:Νυχτερίδα
eml:Pipistrel
es:Chiroptera
eo:Kiropteroj
eu:Saguzar
fa:خفاش
fo:Flogmýs
fr:Chiroptera
ga:Ialtóg
gd:Ialtag
gl:Morcegos
gan:簷老鼠
hak:Phi̍t-phò-è
xal:Бавуха
ko:박쥐
hi:चमगादड़
hr:Šišmiši
io:Vespertilio
id:Kelelawar
ia:Vespertilion
is:Leðurblaka
it:Chiroptera
he:עטלפים
jv:Lawa
pam:Talibatab
ka:ხელფრთიანები
kk:Қолқанаттылар
rn:Agahungarema
sw:Popo
ht:Chòvsourit
ltg:Plykspuorņi
la:Chiroptera
lv:Sikspārņi
lt:Šikšnosparniai
lij:Chiroptera
li:Vleermuis
ln:Ngɛmbo
hu:Denevérek
mk:Лилјаци
ml:വവ്വാൽ
mr:वटवाघूळ
ms:Kelawar
mdf:Веньдряв
my:လင်းနို့
nah:Tzinācantli
nl:Vleermuizen
ne:चमेरो
ja:コウモリ
frr:Fladermüsen
no:Flaggermus
nn:Flaggermus
nrm:Caûque-souothis
nov:Chiroptera
oc:Chiroptera
koi:Кушборддэз
pcd:Soerie-volante
pms:Ratavolòira
pl:Nietoperze
pt:Morcego
ro:Chiroptere
rm:Utschè-mezmieur
qu:Masu
ru:Рукокрылые
sah:Илии кынаттаахтар аймахтара
sc:Chiroptera
sco:Baukie
stq:Flädderdierte
sq:Lakuriqi i natës
scn:Taddarita (armalu)
simple:Bat
sk:Netopiere
sl:Netopirji
sr:Слепи мишеви
sh:Šišmiš
su:Kalong
fi:Lepakot
sv:Fladdermöss
tl:Paniki
ta:வௌவால்
te:గబ్బిలం
th:ค้างคาว
tg:Кӯршапарак
chy:Méšenonetsénóne
tr:Yarasa
uk:Кажани
ur:چمگاڈر
vi:Bộ Dơi
war:Kabog
yo:Àdán
zh-yue:蝙蝠
zea:Vleermuzen
zh:蝙èﾝ
```

What's the most pythonic way to delete everything between "af" and "zh"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing some Wikipedia parsing, and had a similar problem. However, not all the pages I was parsing had that text at the bottom, so I never solved the problem.

Here's something to get you started. Play around with index vs rindex, and check for off-by-ones.

```
def delete_everything_in_between(st, start, end):
    first_index = st.index(start)
    second_index = st.index(end)
    return st[:first_index] + st[second_index:]

delete_everything(st, 'af', 'zh')
```

Of course, if you're willing to assume the garbage text is always at the end of the input, you can just find the first index and return st[:first_index].

Comment: Thanks a lot... I ended up just doing some RegEx like this:

re.sub('a.:.*?z.:', '', wiki, flags=re.DOTALL)